# If $f(g(x))=x$ for all $x$, how few solutions could $g(f(x))=x$ have?

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

This question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2351951/one-way-inverse).

Consider a function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and its left-inverse $f$
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} : f(g(x))=x $$
Then
$$g(f(x))=x $$
has a set of solutions (usually a set with the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$. For example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2351960/89671) constructs $f$ and $g$ such that the solution set is an interval, and if $f$ is a true inverse of $g$ then the solution set is all of $\mathbb{R}$). But how few solutions can it have? Is there some $f,g$ for which it has countably many solutions? Finitely many? One? None?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever $x$ lies in the image of $g$, it must satisfy $g(f(x)) = x$, since if $x=g(y)$, then

$$g(f(x)) = g(f(g(y)) = g(y) = x.$$

However if $g$ has a left inverse $f$ it must be injective:

$$g(x) = g(y) \implies f(g(x)) = f(g(y)) \implies x=y.$$

Therefore $g$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to its image $g(\mathbb{R})$, and so the solution set $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R} : g(f(x)) = x\}$, which satisfies $g(\mathbb{R})\subseteq S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$.